# "travail" devient-il "travaux" pour un emploi ?

Tags: vocabulaire

Est-ce que le mot *travail* devient-il *travaux* au pluriel lorsque l'on parle d'un emploi ?
*Exemple:
 Cet homme a deux travaux* 
pour
 *Cet homme a deux emplois*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Il y a dans ce cas précis une exception :

> travail \tʁa.vaj\ masculin (pluriel : travaux, sauf dans le sens de activité professionnelle, emploi, où c’est le pluriel travails qui est utilisé ; travails est aussi parfois utilisé pour d’autres sens)

source: [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/travail)

Answer (score 2):

C'est *peut-être* l'unique exception à la règle. Quand on parle d'une activité professionnelle c’est le pluriel **travails** qui est utilisé.